# What to do with template typenames for optional arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++11

First of all, the code:

```
template<typename Func, typename Func2>
void ForEachField(Func normalHandler, Func2 arrayHandler = NULL, bool skipUnknowns = true)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < mFields.size(); ++i)
    {
        Field *f = mFields[i];

        if(skipUnknowns && f->IsUnknown())
            continue;

        if(f->GetCount() == 1 || !arrayHandler)
            normalHandler(f);
        else
            arrayHandler(f);
    }
}
```

And an example of usage:

```
df->ForEachField(
    [&](Field *field) { f << "\t" << format("public $%s;\n") % field->GetName(); },
    [&](Field *field) { f << "\t" << format("public $%s;\n") % field->GetName() % field->GetSize(); }
); // Works

df->ForEachField(
    [&](Field *field) { WriteLine(f, format("\t\t'%s' => array('type' => '%s'),") % field->GetName() % field->GetTypeInfo()->Name);
}); // Doesn't work
```

The second call doesn't work because it says:

> OutputPhp.cpp(27): error C2783: 'void
>   DataFile::ForEachField(Func,Func2,bool)'
>   : could not deduce template argument
>   for 'Func2'
>             see declaration of 'DataFile::ForEachField'

Is there any way I can make the second parameter optional, while still using templates, and while not having to manually specify the second template argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an overload for `ForEachField`:

```
template<typename Func>
void ForEachField (Func normalHandler)
{
    ForEachField<Func, void *>(normalHandler, NULL, true);
}
```

Comment: This is actually a great idea. Obviously it should be `ForEachField<Func, void *>` or I will run into the same problem ;) But now I ran into another problem.. !arrayHandler if arrayHandler is a lambda doesn't work, trying to find a solution now :O

Comment: Ok, well the original version did compile though i didn't run it.

Answer (score 1):

I know that code duplication is usually regarded as "bad", however in this case I would probably NOT use a runtime check to detect whether or not I passed an argument... whenever the check can be done at compile time...

```
template<typename Func, typename Func2>
void ForEachField(Func normalHandler, Func2 arrayHandler, bool skipUnknowns = true)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < mFields.size(); ++i)
    {
        Field *f = mFields[i];

        if(skipUnknowns && f->IsUnknown()) { continue; }

        if(f->GetCount() == 1) { normalHandler(f); }
        else { arrayHandler(f); }
    }
}


template<typename Func>
void ForEachField(Func normalHandler, bool skipUnknowns = true)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < mFields.size(); ++i)
    {
        Field *f = mFields[i];

        if(skipUnknowns && f->IsUnknown()) { continue; }

        if(f->GetCount() == 1) { normalHandler(f); }
    }
}
```

Remember that you can perfectly overload functions templates as usual.

This will in turn solve the two problems:

- Second parameter is now optional (for all intents and purposes)
- No more application of `operator!` on a lambda (which does not work)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using C++0x features already (lambdas), just use another one: default template arguments

```
template<typename Func, typename Func2 = void*>
void ForEachField(Func normalHandler, Func2 arrayHandler = NULL, bool skipUnknowns = true)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: `error C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template`

Comment: Must be a difference between g++ and MSVC++. It works on g++.

Comment: Yup, MSVC doesn't support that yet. (And since both compilers are missing support for major parts of C++0x, it's a bit optimistic to say "just use another C++0x feature":))

Answer (score 0):

What about making the second parameter non-default, and creating an overloaded wrapper method that takes a single `typename Func` parameter.